# How to add one more value to the $_POST array in PFBC

Tags: php, arrays, pfbc

I'm using PFBC (http://www.imavex.com/pfbc3.x-php5/) to generate form fields. I made some changes to the name of the elements: changed the `class Textbox extends \PFBC\Element` to `class T_GENERAL extends \PFBC\Element`

And I use

```
$form->addElement(new Element\T_GENERAL("", "cod_postal", array( 
"required" => 1,
"placeholder" => "*Postcode:",
)));
```

to generate a form with 1 field. When I submit the form I have S_POST with this array:

```
array (size=1)
  'cod_postal' => string '7000' (length=4)
```

and then transform this array to a string like this:

```
[["cod_postal","7000"]]
```

I need to add to the $_POST array one more value to be like this :

```
[["cod_postal","7000","0"]] --> $Label_1, $Value_1, $Type_1
```

I defined `define("T_GENERAL", 0);`

How I can do this ?

Comment: How to pass the type value based on T_GENERAL in to the S_POST or the form field ?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake S_POST = $_POST